# Using Graphics In Multiple Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I was getting framerates of below 3 on my Ray marching program and I thought that if I tried multithreading it so each thread can do half the work than if there was no multithreading. I, unfortunately, know nothing about using threads in java so my program makes a thread every time the render method is called. Heres the render method, it is just in a while loop.

```
void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                    for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x+=2) {
                        g.setColor(calculateColor(x,y));
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                    for(int x = 1; x < WIDTH; x+=2) {
                        g.setColor(calculateColor(x,y));
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?
Regards,
GLS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach should work, in general.  However, it looks like your example is flawed.  You're telling both threads to do basically *the exact same thing*?  I compared the two chunks of code in the `run` methods, and they're essentially identical.  The only difference is that one starts `x` at 0, and the other at 1.

Another question I had when I saw your code was:  Is `Graphics` thread-safe?  Because it's being told to call `setColor` and `drawLine` by two different threads, possibly simultaneously. If the `Graphics` object is not thread-safe, you're going to run into issues, even if it does run faster.

I did some looking around, and couldn't find confirmation if `Graphics2D` is thread-safe, so I would assume it is not.  You'd have to approach this in a different way.

Comment: I changed some things in my code so now I use a synchronized method to set a pixel in a buffered image which every time after I call the threads, I draw to screen then flush. Unfortunately, this did not help the framerate that well, got about 1 extra.

Comment: Ok, Found out what's wrong. Java uses primarily the CPU to run. which means if I try to do more than 1 thread, the CPU has to work the extra effort. so the CPU would go to 100% and the program slows down.